# Selenium: move Mouse

Tags: selenium

Task is to move physical cursor to the element.

1. Driver correctly finds element on the page.

   WebElement label = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='loginForm']")).
2. Move cursor does not work.

Tried following:

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(label, 1, 1).click().build().perform();
```

And following:

```
Actions act = new Actions(getDriver());
act.moveToElement(label).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to use Robot class and use there - mouseMove

Comment: What Robot class you mean? Where I can find it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='loginForm']")).equals(driver.switchTo().activeElement())